# Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, updates, lts

I have Ubuntu 11.10 server , I want to upgrade it to 12.04LTS but the update manager show that the new release is 12.04.03LTS, how can I get 12.04LTS ?

Answer (score 1):

12.04.03 LTS is 12.04 LTS. The last number just shows that the latest patches and security fixes are included.

Since it would be quite annoying having to download and install lots of updates on a freshly installed 12.04, Canonical from time to time creates these maintenance releases with all patches up to that point included. Think of them like Service Packs for Windows.